SOIC 8 pin Identification
It was burned due to reversed polarity, so part of code has been damaged. All remain is
UTC WLT4 

in the first row, and
B*208G

on the second.
The device is outdoor camera (Xiaomi XVV Panoramic) the board is handling CMOS module, infrared backlight connectors, etc. The device is got power under 12V, but I think, step down to 5V for CMOS and so on. After reversed polarity connection there were two components that was burned out. One was DC-DC step down stabilizer in a SOT23-6 package, that I hope I already identifyed, and the second is this 8 pin SOIC.
All I found out, that UTC may refer to Unisonic Technologies - a Taiwan company, but on their website has no product that would be similar to these provided codes.



Maybe this: https://en.unisonic.com.tw/uploadfiles/836/part_no_pdf/BA6208.pdf From: https://en.unisonic.com.tw/searching.htm  BA6208 LINEAR INTEGRATED CIRCUIT
Copyright © 2024 Unisonic Technologies Co., Ltd QW-R109-004.I
REVERSIBLE MOTOR DRIVER

@ChrisKnudsen I think you should convert your comment into an answer. Based upon the datasheet marking code information you seem to have identified the device (allowing for one character of the marking being damaged).

From en.unisonic.com.tw/uploadfiles/836/part_no_pdf/BA6208.pdf, found by searching for '208' under: en.unisonic.com.tw/searching.htm, this appears to be a BA6208, REVERSIBLE MOTOR DRIVER.
Description:

The UTC BA6208 is designed for driving reversible motor use, it contain[s] a logic section to controls forward and reverse rotations as well as forced stop, and an output power section is able to supply an output current of up to 100mA (typical) according to the logic control.
The IC allow control of reversible motors in cassette players and other electrical equipment by using TTL-level logic signals."

en.unisonic.com.tw/uploadfiles/836/part_no_pdf/BA6208.pdf, page 1.
Chip marking:

en.unisonic.com.tw/uploadfiles/836/part_no_pdf/BA6208.pdf, page 2.
Pin Function:

en.unisonic.com.tw/uploadfiles/836/part_no_pdf/BA6208.pdf, page 2.

Thank you very much! I'll try it.
